# Migration Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, migration

display me this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/arO2m.jpg and i'm trying to run this migration  specially this part:

```
   Schema::table('materias',function(Blueprint $table)
    {
       $table->foreign('horarios_id')->references('id')->on('horarios')->onDelete('cascade');
       $table->foreign('periodos_id')->references('id')->on('periodos')->onDelete('cascade');
       $table->foreign('tipotareas_id')->references('id')->on('tipotareas')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

i can create https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qIG0.jpg but the left FK cannot create.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7X7J3whQ this the code and  https://github.com/ito2307/utpmatricula/tree/master/database/migrations

Comment: inside `materias table` you assigned unique key you need to add `nullable` for each column.

Comment: not still the same message

Comment: @eduardoyahoo2307 , please provide more information about your migrations. It would be helpful to see your table relationships and structure.